# Combining the result of two queries to one result SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying t create a `compare`, now i'm only able to make it as multiple result (two different result).

[image]

both of the result above is from two queries.

My first result query

```
SELECT 
    customercode,
    CONVERT(DATE, TransDate) transdate,
    SUM(TotalReceivable) AS total 
FROM 
    SalesOrderHeader 
WHERE
    CustomerCode = 'K-MDMM4' 
    AND TransDate BETWEEN '2016-07-25' AND '2016-07-30'
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(DATE, TransDate), customercode
```

and my second query

```
SELECT
    b.OutletCode AS outlet,
    tanggal, 
    (cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50 + 
    isnull(spesial_item,0)) total 
FROM
    transaksi a 
LEFT JOIN
    Outlet b ON a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
LEFT JOIN
    area c ON b.areacode = c.areacode 
WHERE
    b.active = 1 
    AND b.OutletCode LIKE 'K-MDMM4' 
    AND flag = 1 
    AND tanggal BETWEEN '2016-07-25' AND '2016-07-30' 
GROUP BY 
    b.OutletCode, tanggal, cash, cc, dc, flash, 
    piutang, reject, disc50, spesial_item, ba, mpm, tf, 
    ul,remarks 
ORDER BY 
    tanggal DESC
```

I  want this result.

```
    customercode | transdate | total_tbl1 | total_tbl2
      K-MDMM4      2016-07-25  6004050       6004050
      K-MDMM4      2016-07-26  6880340       6880340
      K-MDMM4      2016-07-27  5745040       5745040
      K-MDMM4      2016-07-28  7424820       7424820
```

I can't use jsfiddle :(. I don't know why. I can't create table via queries.

From now, I have this query

```
SELECT
    b.OutletCode AS outlet,
    tanggal,
    (cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50 + 
    isnull(spesial_item, 0)) total, 
    SUM(d.TotalReceivable) AS total 
FROM
    transaksi a 
LEFT JOIN
    Outlet b ON a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
LEFT JOIN
    area c ON b.areacode = c.areacode 
LEFT JOIN
    salesorderheader d ON CONVERT(DATE, a.tanggal) = CONVERT(DATE, d.transdate) 
WHERE
    b.active = 1 
    AND b.BrandCode LIKE '%%'
    AND b.OutletCode LIKE '%%' 
    AND flag = 1 
    AND YEAR(tanggal) = '2016' 
    AND MONTH(tanggal) = '7' 
    AND outlet = 'K-MDMM4'
GROUP BY
    OutletCode, tanggal, cash, cc, dc, flash,
    piutang, reject, disc50, spesial_item, transdate, totalreceivable
ORDER BY
    tanggal DESC
```

and the result so far from my desired result....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine both queries into a single join and select

```
SELECT tbl1.customercode,
       CAST(tbl1.transdate AS DATE) AS transdate,
       tbl1.total AS total_tbl1,
       tbl2.total AS total_tbl2
FROM
(
-- Query 1
SELECT customercode,convert(date,TransDate) transdate,SUM(TotalReceivable) as total 
                FROM SalesOrderHeader 
                where CustomerCode = 'K-MDMM4' 
                and TransDate between '2016-07-25' and '2016-07-30'
                group by convert(date,TransDate),customercode
) AS tbl1
INNER JOIN (
-- Query 2
select b.OutletCode as outlet,tanggal, (cash + cc + dc + flash + piutang + reject + disc50 + 
    isnull(spesial_item,0)) total From transaksi a 
        left join Outlet b on a.Outlet = b.OutletCode
        left join area c on b.areacode = c.areacode 
        where b.active = 1 and b.OutletCode like 'K-MDMM4' and flag = 1 and tanggal 
        between '2016-07-25' and '2016-07-30' 
        group by b.OutletCode,tanggal,cash,cc,dc,flash,piutang,reject,disc50,spesial_item,ba,mpm,tf,ul,remarks
) AS tbl2 ON tbl2.outlet = tbl1.customercode AND CAST(tbl2.trnggal AS DATE) = CAST(tbl1.transdate AS DATE)
order by CAST(tbl1.transdate AS DATE) DESC;
```

Comment: thanks man, it's work. The `order by` part give me an error. I put it at the end of the query and the error is gone

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a database installed on this PC but what you're looking for is:

```
SELECT val1, val2 FROM
(SELECT1_of_your_code AS table1) INNER JOIN 
(SELECT2_of_your_code AS table2) ON
table1.x == table2.y
```

Comment: please comment on downvotes- this was the first solution posted and even it is not a copy/paste solution in my opinion it includes all the information needed to solve the problem described